Matplotlib.scatter documentation covers some parameters unclearly
I was searching for how to plot a scatter plot with points that have a transparent face but coloured edges.  This page gave some ideas, but I find the behaviour of some arguments to differ than reported there.  For example, one answer describes argument c as affecting both face color and edge color, causing arguments for the latter two to be ignored.  In contrast I found the following to be synonymous: c, color, facecolor, facecolors.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
xy = np.random.randint(10,size=[2,10])
colors = sns.color_palette('deep',10)
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi']=100

# These have the same effect (solid faces)
plt.clf(); plt.scatter( *xy, s=10000, c=colors )
plt.clf(); plt.scatter( *xy, s=10000, color=colors )
plt.clf(); plt.scatter( *xy, s=10000, facecolor=colors )
plt.clf(); plt.scatter( *xy, s=10000, facecolors=colors )

# These have the same effect (transparent faces, solid edges)
plt.clf(); plt.scatter( *xy, s=10000, edgecolors=colors, c='None' )
plt.clf(); plt.scatter( *xy, s=10000, edgecolors=colors, color='None' )
plt.clf(); plt.scatter( *xy, s=10000, edgecolors=colors, facecolor='None' )
plt.clf(); plt.scatter( *xy, s=10000, edgecolors=colors, facecolors='None' )

I also found that all 4 arguments are mentioned in the documentation but only c is listed as a pyplot.scatter() argument.  Hence, the others don't get a detailed description.
I thought that the documentation is definitive and covers all possible arguments.  Why do the other arguments not appear in the argument list?  I think that's part of the reason why there is confusion about their interactions, e.g., when some arguments override others.

It is listed in the plt.scatter documentation, at "Other Parameters" section, that the **kwargs are Collection properties. There you find the edgecolors and facecolors descriptions. I do concede that the interaction with the color argument is not described.

Interestingly, in the ax.scatter, the edgecolors argument is listed.

Also, in both documentations the difference between c and color is explained: "Note that c should not be a single numeric RGB or RGBA sequence because that is indistinguishable from an array of values to be colormapped [...] If you wish to specify a single color for all points prefer the color keyword argument".

@paime: In your Collections link, I found facecolors, which accounts for one more of the 4 arguments.  The entire page is huge and the other arguments appear in other places (pertaining to other methods).  It seems that newcomers need to browse through a lot of disparate sections of various documentation to come up with a complete picture, and assumptions are needed about what parameters found in one context are also available in another context.  I get that c and color are mentioned (I say this in my question).

Maybe matplotlib's github issues is a better place to discuss improvements to the documentation? The code has grown organically during many years, often trying not to break older code. An exact description of all parameters, how they have subtle differences and how they interact can be a huge effort, and there don't seem to be a lot of volunteers for this task. Also, the inner workings might change unexpectedly in future versions. The code base is gigantic, and constantly changing; getting a perfect documentation is a laudable goal, but hard to achieve.

I suspect you're right.  I come from a Matlab background, and their documentation is likely driven by user sentiments and not resourced on a volunteer basis.

TLDR: c applies to both fc and ec, but specifying them overrides c "inheritance".
I agree that there are multiple possibilities and that not every interaction is documented.
However, I think this is because that way the beginner will find the most obvious use case more easily, and if they needs more complex usage they can dig deeper and in the end a few lines of codes will give the answer, as demonstrated below:

First row demonstrates that facecolors, facecolor and fc are synonyms, as for edgecolors, edgecolor and ec;
Second row demonstrates the interaction when fc and/or ec is 'none';
Third row demonstrates that c applies to both fc and ec when they are not specified. You can see that when only c=fc is specified then the markers are bigger than when c='none' and fc=fc, because in the last case c='none' implies ec='none' since ec is not explicitly defined.


Code to reproduce:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N, s, lw = 10, 90, 2

xy = np.random.randint(N, size=(2, N))
facecolors = np.random.rand(N, 3)
edgecolors = np.random.rand(N, 3)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3, figsize=(10, 7))

axes[0, 0].set_title("facecolors=fc, edgecolors=ec")
axes[0, 0].scatter(*xy, s=s, lw=lw, facecolors=facecolors, edgecolors=edgecolors)

axes[0, 1].set_title("facecolor=fc, edgecolor=ec")
axes[0, 1].scatter(*xy, s=s, lw=lw, facecolor=facecolors, edgecolor=edgecolors)

axes[0, 2].set_title("fc=fc, ec=ec")
axes[0, 2].scatter(*xy, s=s, lw=lw, fc=facecolors, ec=edgecolors)

axes[1, 0].set_title("fc=fc, ec='none'")
axes[1, 0].scatter(*xy, s=s, lw=lw, fc=facecolors, ec="none")

axes[1, 1].set_title("fc='none', ec=ec")
axes[1, 1].scatter(*xy, s=s, lw=lw, fc="none", ec=edgecolors)

axes[1, 2].set_title("fc='none', ec='none'")
axes[1, 2].scatter(*xy, s=s, lw=lw, fc="none", ec="none")

axes[2, 0].set_title("c=fc, ec=ec")
axes[2, 0].scatter(*xy, s=s, lw=lw, c=facecolors, ec=edgecolors)

axes[2, 1].set_title("c=fc")
axes[2, 1].scatter(*xy, s=s, lw=lw, c=facecolors)

axes[2, 2].set_title("c=fc, ec='none'")
axes[2, 2].scatter(*xy, s=s, lw=lw, c=facecolors, ec="none")

axes[2, 2].set_title("c='none', fc=fc")
axes[2, 2].scatter(*xy, s=s, lw=lw, c="none", fc=facecolors)

fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()


Thanks, paime.  I believe that your table serves as a valuable reference, not just for me.
